# Rails 3 Carrierwave How to delete file which is an attribute of a model?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, formtastic, carrierwave, activeadmin

I followed the Railcast #253 http://railscasts.com/episodes/253-carrierwave-file-uploads and works great. But then I implemented it with ActiveAdmin and therefore Formtastic (ActiveAdmin uses Formtastic for the forms).

So I'm able to upload files and download files.

Problem is, it seems that Carrierwave expects a model instead of an attribute of the model when linking to **remove** links.

I have model Shipment, which has hbl_pdf attribute (a PDF document). This is my delete link...

```
row("HBL") { link_to 'remove', shipment.hbl_pdf, :confirm => "Are you sure?", :method => :delete }
```

I get error... `undefined method model_name for PdfUploader:Class`

I don't want to delete the shipment, only the document.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Why aren't you calling `remove_hbl_pdf!` on the shipment object instead?  Read the "Removing uploaded files" section of this: https://github.com/jnicklas/carrierwave#readme

```
link_to 'remove', remove_shipment_pdf_path(shipment), :confirm => "Are you sure?", :method => :delete
```

and in your controller

```
def remove_shipment_pdf
  shipment = Shipment.find_by_id(params[:shipment_id])
  shipment.remove_hbl_pdf! if shipment
  # respond with something or redirect
end
```

The syntax for the remove command is based on the name of your attribute.  So if your model attribute name is `.hbl_pdf` then it is `remove_hbl_pdf!` and if it was `.image` then it would be `remove_image!`